# Custom node version to run VSCode extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm making a vscode extension for my personal use. I'd really like to use a more recent node version. However, I'm not sure how does VSCode chooses which node version to use.

The only node.js that I have installed is `8.1.3`. But when I debug the extension, I see that VSCode uses `7.*.*` (via `process.version`).

I've been searching documentation for an hour, so far, without luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since it is open-source, if you were super-ambitious you could fork vscode and build it on top of a different version of electron. Electron itself runs on a forked version of nodejs as you can see at https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/master/vendor... https://github.com/electron/node. Good luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. Quoting the reply of one of the team members (Andre Weinand) in [#18253](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18253#issuecomment-271235914):

> VS Code runs extensions on the node version that is built into electron (on which VS Code is based). This cannot be changed.