# Google Cloud Speech Recognition grpc version incompatible with VSCode Electron Version

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, vscode-extensions

My goal is to develop a VS Code extension with speech recognition, ideally via google's API.

When attempting to import and use `@google-cloud/speech`, the following error is thrown at runtime:

`Error: @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0`

VS Code (as of 6/20/2019) is running electron 3.18 and node.js 10.2.0. Does this mean there is no way to work around this issue?

I'm following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it should work starting with the next release then. From the [preliminary 1.36 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_36.md#nodejs-update):

> The Electron version that VS Code runs on has been updated and brings with it an update to Node.js from `10.2.0` to `10.11.0`. All extensions will now run on this newer version of Node.js.

To make sure, you can try an [Insider's build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Generally speaking though, there's no way to control what Node version VSCode extension run on (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062881/custom-node-version-to-run-vscode-extensions)), so I guess you got lucky here. :)

Comment: Just found this as you posted it -- it appears to resolve the crash! This solution works well enough for me :)