# Module compiled against a different NODE_MODULE_VERSION when developing an extension for vscode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, vscode-extensions, treesitter

I'm trying to use node's tree-sitter package in my vscode extension, but I get the following error:

> Activating extension 'extension name' failed: The module '.../node_modules/tree-sitter/build/Release/tree_sitter_runtime_binding.node'
> was compiled against a different Node.js version using
> NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
> NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
> the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)..

From what I understand, the NODE_MODULE_VERSION is the version of node's ABI. However, I couldn't even find a release of node that has NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89 in the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

### What I've tried:

- Deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling the packages.
- Running `npm rebuild tree-sitter --update-binary` from the top directory.
- Rebuilding the tree-sitter package with `node-gyp rebuild` and `node-gyp rebuild --target=(my node version)` from the `node_modules/tree-sitter` directory.
- Switching node versions using nvm.

None of that helped. I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062881/custom-node-version-to-run-vscode-extensions) that changing node versions won't help, as I confirmed when I tried

`console.log(process.version); // v14.16.0`

`console.log(process.versions.modules); // 89`

This gave the same output no matter which node version I used. I also tried rebuilding the tree-sitter package using that node version `node-gyp rebuild --target=14.16.0`, but I get the same error, however this time it says the module was compiled using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83, which is consistent with what node's site says.

How do I resolve this error?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, the version of node ABI used by vscode extensions is the ABI version used by vscode's internal electron. [According to this source](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules)

> Native Node.js modules are supported by Electron, but since Electron has a different application binary interface (ABI) from a given Node.js binary (due to differences such as using Chromium's BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL), the native modules you use will need to be recompiled for Electron...

This explains why I couldn't find NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89 in node's site.

Next, I checked what version of electron my build of vscode uses. To do this, I simply checked the package.json that came with vscode (`/usr/lib/code/package.json` on linux, I guess that it is inside the folder vscode is installed on on windows).

Next, following the instructions from electron's site, rebuild the module using the package `electron-rebuild`. To specify a target version, simply run

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -v [version]`

However, I have no source for this but it seems that tree-sitter does not currently support newer versions of electron, so the build fails. This seems to be because of a change in V8's API ([according to this](https://github.com/tree-sitter/node-tree-sitter/issues/90#issuecomment-912722406)).

The author linked his solution [here](https://github.com/sergei-dyshel/node-tree-sitter/commit/961870e07d395c8000a27051b01e01d6cecf7e9b). I copied his changes and the build succeeded.

Note that I had to replace the existing node addon with the newly built one.